# How to set and use a variable in a PostgreSQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need to dynamically create a table everyday.  Currently, this is my working solution:

```
DO
$$
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('

        CREATE TABLE schema.%I (
            id NUMERIC,
            field1 TEXT,
            field2 TEXT
        )
        WITH (
            OIDS=FALSE
        );

        GRANT ALL ON TABLE schema.%I TO role1;
        GRANT ALL ON TABLE schema.%I TO role2;', 

        'table_name_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD'),
        'table_name_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD'),
        'table_name_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')
    );
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, you can see how I have to add an argument to `format` command for every mention of the table I'm trying to create.  Add some constraints, indexes, etc., and this becomes untenable.

How can I accomplish this by setting the table name variable once and then using that over and over again?  Ideally, I would like the solution to be executable from within a PGAdmin query window.  That being said, however, this will end up being stored in a sql file and executed from a script.

I've tried the `/set` thing I've seen all over while searching for a solution, but I always end up with a syntax error starting with the slash.

Comment: I think you should use a procedure there is very easy way to pass value.

Comment: @ShubhamBatra that's a good idea, i'll look into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the position field `n$`

```
EXECUTE format('

    CREATE TABLE schema.%1$I (
        id NUMERIC,
        field1 TEXT,
        field2 TEXT
    )
    WITH (
        OIDS=FALSE
    );

    GRANT ALL ON TABLE schema.%1$I TO role1;
    GRANT ALL ON TABLE schema.%1$I TO role2;', 

    'table_name_' || to_char(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')
);
```

Comment: not exactly what i was expecting, but mitigates the exact problem i was trying to solve; excellent answer, thank you!  for what it's worth (for others reading this thread), @ShubhamBatra is correct that i should be using a stored procedure for this type of task.

Comment: @liltitus27 An `execute` will be necessary regardless of if `function` or `anonymous block` is being used